# How can I make this PDO mysql query with if statements work correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am building a web site from scratch for a little project.

I have stumbled across a little problem of mine and have scratched my head over it to no avail! Here is my code;

```
else if (isset($_POST['hidden']) && $_POST['hidden'] = 1) {

$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_POST['username']));

    if ($q -> rowCount() > 0) {
        echo 'USERNAME TAKEN<br />';
    }

$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_POST['email']));

    if ($q -> rowCount() > 0) {
        echo 'EMAIL TAKEN<br />';
    }

    else {
        $q = $dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (fname, lname, email, password, username, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");       $q -> execute(array($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['gender']));
        echo 'YOUR ACCOUNT NEEDS ACTIVATING';
    }
}
```

Now my problem lies with checking if the username and email are already taken.

I have one if statement for checking the username.

I have one if statement for checking the email.

And I have one else statement for inserting the data into the mysql table if all is good.

The problem I have is that is the username is the same, and the email is not then the else statement still fires, I know it does as I have on my html document

'USERNAME TAKEN' & 'ACCOUNT NEEDS ACTIVATING'

I thought about putting them in 'else if' statements but I need both the username and email to work together not if one works then not the other. Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're aware that `$_POST['hidden'] = 1` is an assignment, not a boolean check (for different cases)?

Comment: What do you mean? please elaborate, I am using it so if the user is signing up it will do that and if they are not it will do something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
else if (isset($_POST['hidden']) && $_POST['hidden'] = 1) {


    $q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username = ?");
    $q -> execute(array($_POST['username']));
    $username_taken = $q->rowCount() > 0;

    $q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
    $q -> execute(array($_POST['email']));

    $email_taken = $q->rowCount() > 0;

    if ($username_taken || $email_taken) {
        if ($username_taken) {
            echo 'USERNAME TAKEN<br />';
        }
        if ($email_taken) {
            echo 'EMAIL TAKEN<br />';
        }
    }
    else {
        $q = $dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (fname, lname, email, password, username, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");       $q -> execute(array($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['gender']));
        echo 'YOUR ACCOUNT NEEDS ACTIVATING';
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked great thanks :) Didn't think about approaching it like this, thanks alot!